# Can you disable some blueprints on a specific controller?

Tags: sails.js

Is there a known way to disable specific `blueprints` on the per-controller level in `sails.js`?

I've read how to disable ALL `blueprints` on the app level, and how to disable ALL `blueprints` for an individual `controller` but is there a way to disable a subset of the `blueprints` on an individual `controller`?

This documentation covers the basics, including disabling all `blueprints` per controller,
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/blueprint-api/blueprint-api.md

But say I have a `Counties` model and I want the `find` actions available (`find()` and `findOne()`), but do not want the others.

Is that an option?

Comment: If you dont want to expose these blueprints, why not just use policies and restrict access instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override them in the controllers. For example,

```
  update: function (req, res) {
    res.forbidden();
  },  

  destroy: function (req, res) {
    res.forbidden();
  }
```

This is one way. Other and more preferred way is to use policies:

```
  myController: {
    'find': true,
    'findOne': true,
    '*': false
  },
```

This will only expose find and findOne and hide other actions